# Xamarin.Forms Change APP Icon

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

There is something strange in my Visual Studio 2015
when I change (not even replace) the icon image for Android in Resources --> drawable --> + subs
than my visual studio won't build an show me the following error:

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with
>   value '@drawable/icon')
>   it points to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

If I revert to my old revision of this map it will work ? 
but this is not what we want of course.

BE AWARE the resource does exist and have the correct dimensions etc.

Does someone knows what I'm doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Its very strange after revert to old revision of the Resources map i replace them and rebuild and its still showing the old icon in application but the error is gone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think if you use Visual Studio 2015 you can generate the wanted app icon with a online generator.

Then you put the specific generated image files like

- Icon-hdpi.png
- Icon-xhdpi.png
- Icon-xxhdpi.png

into the specific directories of your Android Project

- /Resources/drawable-hdpi
- /Resources/drawable-xhdpi
- /Resources/drawable-xxhdpi

The last step is to select the inserted images as your app icon via your AndroidManifest file.

For more information visit that link:

[Specify the Application Icon](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/#Specify_the_Application_Icon/%22Specify%20the%20Application%20Icon%22)

Answer (score 1):

Last time I found myself chasing that particular error message it was because the file name had changed from icon to Icon. Its case sensitive. Not sure if its the same issue but thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: Not its exact the same file name dimensions etc it is there now but he uses the old one :( ty for your help